# itextsharp creating a new pdf/a from bytes

Tags: c#, itext, pdfa

Is it possible to create a pdfa from a file (.pdf) converted to bytes. Because i think there is no direct coversion of pdf to pdf/a.

I'm quite lost on how to do it and I can't seem to find any tutorials on how to do.

Comment: *create a pdfa from bytes of a file* - do you mean the pdf/a should show something like a hex dump of those bytes?

Comment: @mklm ahh, sorry, ill edit my post.

Comment: As far as I know there is no one-liner api for pdf-to-pdfa conversion. Depending on which PDF/A variant you're talking about, it may be more or less feasible using itext low level apis.

Comment: There is a difference between regular PDF and PDF/A, because PDF/A has something extra. You need to provide that something extra, e.g. missing fonts, or structure (Tagged PDF) in the case of PDF/A level A, and so on. The fonts were originally present and the data may have been structured to start with, but the fonts and the structure got lost in the process of making an ordinary PDF. The PDF should have been created as a PDF/A file to start with. Your question sounds like: I have made carrot soup, now I want to convert that soup back to carrots. Don't do that; get new carrots instead!

Comment: @BrunoLowagie ahh, i see, the reason that i want to convert it to pdf/a is because our rdlc creates it in pdf, and pdf only.